# Within .xlsx file, how do I insert a column, and fill this from cell A2 to max row?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

Please see my code below to try and solve the title. The part that doesn't work begins with "for row_num" where I want to fill column A with a single value. I don't get an error message but when I open the file, I see a cell A1 with "Form ID" but rows A2 to the max row in column A are blank (when I want all of these to contain "Test ID". Thanks.

```
wb = load_workbook(filename = 'H:/Hello.xlsx')
ws = wb.worksheets[0]
sheet_names = wb.get_sheet_names()
name = wb.sheetnames[0]
sheet_ranges = wb[name]
df = pd.DataFrame(sheet_ranges.values)
sheet = wb.worksheets[0]
max_row = sheet.max_row
sheet.insert_cols(0)
ws['A1'] = "Form ID"
for row_num in range(2, max_row):
    cell = xl_rowcol_to_cell(row_num, 1)
    worksheet.write(row_num, 1, 'TESTID')
wb.save("Hello.xlsx")
```

**Before:**

```
xl   Date   Value
0     1      2
1     2      4
2     3      6
3     4      8
4     5     10
5     6     12
```

**Desired Output:**

```
xl    Form_ID      Date   Value
0     ABC           1      2
1     ABC           2      4
2     ABC           3      6
3     ABC           4      8
4     ABC           5     10
5     ABC           6     12
```

Comment: Please post sample screenshot for clarity, it's not easy to understand with words. Or maybe show us a data frame example input and output.

Comment: please post a sample data of how your excel data looks like and how you are expect to convert

Comment: I have provided the before and after above - thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to use Pandas, use its vectorised functionality. There's no need to iterate rows manually:

```
path = r'H:/Hello.xlsx'

# read file into dataframe
df = pd.read_excel(path)

# add series
df['Form_ID'] = 'TESTID'

# order columns
df = df[['xl', 'Form_ID', 'Date', 'Value']]

# export dataframe
df.to_excel(path, index=False)
```

Comment: Thank you - now i get the error message 'AttributeError: 'Book' object has no attribute 'extract_formulas'' and I have the latest version of pandas, xlrd and openpyxl

Comment: I'm not using `xlrd` or `openpyxl`, just `pandas`. In addition, I can't replicate your error. You may need to provide a [mcve], e.g. which line gives you the error?

Comment: Hi, so I have used identical code to you and then the error is with line 6:

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:/Testing.py", line 6, in <module>
    df = pd.read_excel(path)

Comment: So if `pd.read_excel` isn't working for you should ask a separate question. This has nothing to do with adding a column.

Comment: Would using Excel 2016 create any problems with that pandas code?

Comment: No, it shouldn't.

Comment: Hi - now I get the error - do I need to start another thread for this?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:/Testing.py", line 12, in <module>
    df = df[['Form_ID', 'Date', 'Value']]
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list

Comment: @user10069963, Sure, start another thread if you haven't got it working and can't find a solution elsewhere.

Comment: so it turns out the reason the code didn't work initially was due to linking the interpreter to my personal folder - once i stopped that - it worked!